# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, typeerror

Why do I get this error?

```
    a[k] = q % b
 TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Code:

```
def algorithmone(n,b,a):
     assert(b > 1)
     q = n
     k = 0
     while q != 0:
        a[k] = q % b
        q = q / b
        ++k

     return k

print (algorithmone(5,233,676))
print (algorithmone(11,233,676))
print (algorithmone(3,1001,94))
print (algorithmone(111,1201,121))
```

Comment: @JBernardo -- suprisingly, `++k` is valid python syntax -- which is short for "do nothing to k" and return it for *most* objects `k` :-).  `k++` without anything else further to the right is a sure way to crash and burn :).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're passing an integer to your function as `a`.  You then try to assign to it as:  `a[k] = ...` but that doesn't work since `a` is a scalar...

It's the same thing as if you had tried:

```
50[42] = 7
```

That statement doesn't make much sense and python would yell at you the same way (presumably).

Also, `++k` isn't doing what you think it does -- it's parsed as `(+(+(k)))` -- i.e. the bytcode is just `UNARY_POSITIVE` twice.  What you actually want is something like `k += 1`

Finally, be careful with statements like:

```
q = q / b
```

The parenthesis you use with print imply that you want to use this on python3.x at some point.  but, `x/y` behaves differently on python3.x than it does on python2.x.  Looking at the algorithm, I'm guessing you want *integer division* (since you check `q != 0` which would be hard to satisfy with floats).  If that's the case, you should consider using:

```
q = q // b
```

which performs integer division on both python2.x and python3.x.

Comment: It is worth explicitly stating that ++ and -- don't exist in Python.

Comment: @BlackVegetable -- At first I thought that `++k` would be a `SyntaxError`, but it isn't.  (I had to look at the bytecode to figure out what it was doing ... `k++` would be a `SyntaxError` though).

Comment: @mgilson well, it's more or less obvious way to parse `++k` in a language that has the unary `+` but not the `++` :)

Comment: @wRAR -- Sure -- I've just never had any need to use the unary `+` so it wasn't immediately obvious to me!

Comment: What _can_ you use the unary + for in python!?

Comment: originally i had k = k + 1 but i was moving stuff around to try to fix the error but it still didnt help...thanks mgilson, a lot of the stuff i read were from python 2 i guess...its still giving me the error on a[k] = q % b ? should I use a.apend() or something ?

Comment: @wim -- *shrugs*, [overloading on a custom object?](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pos__) -- I can't think of anything else ...

Comment: @agape -- I have no idea.  I don't know what the code you posted is supposed to do.  `a.append` won't work since `int` objects don't have an `append` method.  Perhaps you want to pass a list into the function?

Comment: i wanted to implement a function, the base b expansion of n algorithm

Comment: Well `++t` DOES exist in Python, but so does `++++++t` -- in both cases it does nothing.