# array operation : error : 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, arrays

having a 2 dimensions array, I want clone n*times each of it's items. 
it's exactly like enlarging an image n times on both dimensions.
Here is my code :

```
    def elargir(a,n) :
        imag=[a.shape[0]*n,a.shape[1]*n] # Array with the wanted shape
        for i in range(a.shape[0]): 
           for j in range(a.shape[1]*n): # loops on lines and columns of a
               imag[i][j]=a[i//5][j//n]  
        return imag
```

I create an array

```
    a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

and apply function on it

```
    elargir (a,5)
```

and here is thte error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-14-508f439a1888>", line 1, in <module>
        elargir (a,5)

      File "<ipython-input-12-b2382eb5b301>", line 5, in elargir
        imag[i][j]=a[i//5][j//n]

    TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805306/typeerror-int-object-does-not-support-item-assignment)

Comment: This `imag=[a.shape[0]*n,a.shape[1]*n]` creates a list with two elements: `a.shape[0]*n` and `a.shape[1]*n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imag` is a 1D array. In `for i in range(a.shape[0]):` you will first access the first item of that array, an `int` which you further try to index by `j`. The array in your example does not match what you get in your first block of code.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
n = 3

imag=[a.shape[0]*n,a.shape[1]*n]
print(imag[0]) # The `i` index in your nested for loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. replaced np.array by np.zeros and got the rights shape of imag array

Comment: imag=np.zeros([a.shape[0]*n,a.shape[1]*n])

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense :) If you found that this answer solved your problem then please consider [marking it as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that others know that the issue is solved.