# trying to perform a calculation using values from a list with conditional output (also a list) values and keep getting item assignment error

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, variable-assignment, calculation

I am trying to get an output list by using conditions to determine the values.  For some conditions I want to set the output to a constant and for other conditions I want to perform a calculation from values in another list of values with the same index.  When it gets to the conditions that set the output to an integer I get "TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment".  Here is the code.  How do I fix this?

```
#Load DL values
dl = DL.values()

#Get the length of the dataset
dataset_length2 = DL.size()

#Create temporary lists to store the results
tf_calc = [-9999] * dataset_length2

for idx, val in enumerate(dl):
    if dl[idx] == -9999:
        tf_calc[idx] = -9999
    else:
        if delta_azi[idx] == 0 and st_inc[idx] - st_inc[idx-1] > 0:
            tf_calc[idx] = 0 #<-------------------------------------I get the error here
        elif delta_azi[idx] > 0 and st_inc[idx] - st_inc[idx-1] == 0:
            tf_calc[idx] = 90
        elif delta_azi[idx] == 0 and st_inc[idx] - st_inc[idx-1] < 0:
            tf_calc[idx] = 180
        elif delta_azi[idx] > 0 and st_inc[idx] - st_inc[idx-1] == 0:
            tf_calc[idx] = 270
        elif st_azi[idx] - st_azi[idx-1] > 0 and st_inc[idx] - st_inc[idx-1] > 0:
            tf_calc[idx] = acos((cos(radians(st_inc[idx-1]))*cos(radians(dl[idx-1]))-cos(radians(st_inc[idx])))/(sin(radians(st_inc[idx-1]))*sin(radians(dl[idx-1]))))
        else:  #temporary - more conditions to come
            tf_calc = -9999
        
TF_CALC.setValues(tf_calc)
TF_CALC.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last 'else' condition you wrote as "temporary -more condition to come" is replacing your list saved in tf_calc with the number -9999.

If you replace these lines with:

```
        else:  #temporary - more conditions to come
            tf_calc[idx] = -9999
```

you should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Scarlet for the response, but it does not even make it that far into the code.  I am sure once I get past the current issue I will need to fix that but for the moment It stops at the first condition, if delta_azi[idx] == 0 and st_inc[idx] - st_inc[idx-1] > 0:
            tf_calc[idx] = 0, and gives me  "TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment".  First I need to know what I am doing wrong to get rid of the TypeError.

Comment: The error: "TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment" means that you are trying to do something like `10[idx] = 0`. More infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14805319/19288094).

The only place I could find in your code where your list saved in `tf_calc` is replaced by an integer is in that line. Probably in the previous iteration the code falls in the last case.

If you want to check if it is the case, add a `print("I was here")` in that line. If you see this text in the terminal, you can confirm this was causing the error.

Comment: Thanks again Scarlet.  I figured it out before reading this but you are correct in your description above.  I have since finished the rest of my conditions and everything works as expected now.